# Memory out of range C++

Tags: c++

I am implementing a code for DES. It takes in 8 bytes of data and returns out 8 Bytes of encoded data. Problem occurs when I try to send in a file which has a size exceeding 10 MB,
the stack memory goes out of range. I am freeing up the allocated memory wherever I can but still the error persists.
Here is my code for the same.

```
        // DES.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//
#include<iostream>
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "des.h"
using namespace std;

//loads of const array declarations here
    des::des(const char Key[17]){
        // constructor work
    }

    void des::tokey_56(){
        //works on the keys and converts it to 56 bits.
        tokey_48(); //called to convert to 48 bit keys.
    }

    void leftshift(int a[],int shift){
        //leftshifts a by shif number of bits
    }



    void des::tokey_48(){
        /* */
            //makes 16 subkeys of 48bits each.
    }
    //This function calculates permutation using the const arrays decalared above.
    Byte* des::permute(Byte bytes[],const int permutatn[],int permlen,int bytelen){
        Byte *newbytes=new Byte[permlen/8];
        //init
        for(int i=0;i<permlen/8;i++)
            newbytes[i]=0;
        //initclose
        /*for(int i=0;i<bytelen;i++){
        printf("%d - ",bytes[i]);
        }*/
        for(int i=0;i<permlen;i++){
            int temp=permutatn[i];
            int index1=(permutatn[i]-1)/8;
            int index2=(permutatn[i]-1)%8;
            int tempvar=bytes[index1]&masks[index2];
            int tempvar_1;
            tempvar_1=(tempvar>0)?masks[i%8]:0;
            newbytes[i/8]= newbytes[i/8] | tempvar_1;
            /*if(i==13){
            printf(" %d-%d ",bytes[index1],newbytes[i/8]);
            }*/
        }

        /*for(int i=0;i<permlen/8;i++){
        printf("%d - ",newbytes[i]);
        }*/
        return newbytes;
    }


    void des::create_sub_array(Byte array[], Byte subarray[],int start,int end){
        // creates 2 subarrays from start to end
    }

    void des::swap(Byte a[],Byte b[]){
        // Swaps array a and b
    }

    //This is the main DES function (Key,Right)
    Byte* des::function_des(Byte right[],Byte k[]){
        Byte *right_p=new Byte[6];
        Byte *B=new Byte[8];
        right_p=permute(right,E,48,4);
        for(int i=0;i<6;i++){
            right_p[i]=right_p[i]^k[i];
            //printf(" %d ",right_p[i]);
        }

        B[0]=(right_p[0]&0xFC)>>2;
        B[1]=( ((right_p[0]&0x3 )<<4)|0x0F ) & ( ((right_p[1]&0xF0)>>4)|0xF0 );  
        B[2]=( ((right_p[1]&0x0F)<<2)|0x03 ) & ( ((right_p[2]&0xC0)>>6)|0xFC );
        B[3]=(right_p[2]&0x3F);
        B[4]=(right_p[3]&0xFC)>>2;
        B[5]=( ((right_p[3]&0x3 )<<4)|0x0F ) & ( ((right_p[4]&0xF0)>>4)|0xF0 );  
        B[6]=( ((right_p[4]&0x0F)<<2)|0x03 ) & ( ((right_p[5]&0xC0)>>6)|0xFC );
        B[7]= (right_p[5]&0x3F);

        for(int i=0;i<8;i++){
            int row=( ((B[i]&0x20)>>4)|0x01) & ( (B[i]&0x01)|0x3E);
            int column= (B[i]&0x1E)>>1;
            //using SBoxes
            switch(i){
            case 0: B[0]=S1[row][column];
                break;
            case 1: B[1]=S2[row][column];
                break;
            case 2: B[2]=S3[row][column];
                break;
            case 3: B[3]=S4[row][column];
                break;
            case 4: B[4]=S5[row][column];
                break;
            case 5: B[5]=S6[row][column];
                break;
            case 6: B[6]=S7[row][column];
                break;
            case 7: B[7]=S8[row][column];
                break;
            }
        }
        for(int i=0,j=0; i<4; i++,j+=2){
            B[i]=(B[j]<<4)|(B[j+1]);
        }
        B=permute(B,P,32,4);
        delete[] right_p;
        return B;
    }

    void des::XOR(Byte a[],Byte b[],int len){
        //XOR Function bit by bit.
    }

   //This Function is called from outside the class DES with a 8 byte packet
    Byte* des::encode(Byte bytes[8]){
        Byte *encoded=new Byte[8];
        tokey_56();
        bytes=permute(bytes,IP,64,8);
        Byte left[4],right[4];
        create_sub_array(bytes,left,0,4);
        create_sub_array(bytes,right,4,8);
        //printf("\n\n");
        for(int i=0;i<16;i++){
            Byte *newright=new Byte[4];
            newright=function_des(right,key48[i]);
            XOR(left,newright,4);
            swap(left,right);
            delete[] newright;
        }
        swap(left,right);
        for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
            encoded[i]=left[i];
            encoded[i+4]=right[i];
        }
        encoded=permute(encoded,IPi,64,8);

        //print final coded message
        /*(for(int i=0;i<8;i++){
            printf("%2X",encoded[i]);
        }*/
        return encoded;
    }

    Byte* des::decode(Byte bytes[8]){
        Byte *decoded=new Byte[8];
        tokey_56();
        bytes=permute(bytes,IP,64,8);
        Byte left[4],right[4];
        create_sub_array(bytes,left,0,4);
        create_sub_array(bytes,right,4,8);
        //printf("\n\n");
        for(int i=0;i<16;i++){
            Byte *newright=new Byte[4];
            newright=function_des(right,key48[15-i]);
            XOR(left,newright,4);
            swap(left,right);
            delete[] newright;
        }
        swap(left,right);
        for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
            decoded[i]=left[i];
            decoded[i+4]=right[i];
        }
        decoded=permute(decoded,IPi,64,8);

        /*for(int i=0;i<8;i++){
            printf("%2X",decoded[i]);
        }*/
        return decoded;
    }
```

The Header file for the class DES is declared below.

```
#pragma once
#include<ctype.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include"stdafx.h"
using namespace std;

typedef unsigned char Byte;

class des
{
private:
    static const int PC_1[56];
    static const int PC_2[];
    static const int IP[];
    static const int E[];
    static const int S1[4][16];
    static const int S2[4][16];
    static const int S3[4][16];
    static const int S4[4][16];
    static const int S5[4][16];
    static const int S6[4][16];
    static const int S7[4][16];
    static const int S8[4][16];
    static const int P[];
    static const int IPi[];
    static const char binary[16][5];
    static const Byte masks[8];
    //static const Byte masks_1[8];
    char key[16][5];
    int key_56[56];
    //int key_48[16][48];
    Byte key48[16][6];
public:

    char toBinary();
    des(const char Key[17]);
    void tokey_56();
    void tokey_48();
    Byte* encode(Byte bytes[]);
    Byte* des::decode(Byte bytes[8]);
    Byte* permute(Byte byte[],const int permutatn[],int permlen,int bytelen);
    void create_sub_array(Byte array[],Byte subarray[],int start,int end);
    void swap(Byte a[],Byte b[]);
    void XOR(Byte a[],Byte b[],int len);
    Byte* function_des(Byte right[],Byte k[]);
    ~des(void){}
};
```

Id appreciate some help if someone tells me how to effectively handle the memory given to me.

Comment: Way way too much code. Try stepping through it with a debugger.

Comment: You need to reduce this to a [small self-contained compilable example](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22754/sscce-how-to-provide-examples-for-programming-questions) that just shows the specific problem without all the extraneous crap. (Also, pro tip: you need to do something about all the hard-coded literal constants, for the sake of your own sanity as well as everyone else's.)

Comment: I guess the trouble comes from the content of `_tmain`: the way you load the file content in memory. Could you show that piece of code? (It cannot be a simple `return 0;` that cause a problem)

Comment: It's hard to see it in this much code, but if you're saying you're overflowing the stack, the only possibility for this would be deep recursion. If you have it, you have to restructure the code to eliminate it. If you don't have it, the problem is somewhere else. C++ does not support variable length arrays, AFAIK, so they can't be the reason here (unless supported via a compiler extension).

Comment: Ill try and reduce the code. Do I edit it above or do I post it again?

Comment: Just edit. BTW, if you have access to something like valgrind or purify, learn how to use them.

Comment: I have not used valgrind or purify. I hope I have made the code readable.

Comment: @SilentPro: How do you know that the "stack memory goes out of range"? Are you sure it's the stack? Because I don't see any recursion here and allocating a few megabytes in not enough to exhaust the whole address space.

Comment: Visual c++ points that out to me.
U will not see any recursion here because this part is only accepting 64 bits decoding or encoding it and returning it.
For a file size of say 10MB when the encode method is called repeatedly for (1024 x 1024 x 10 x 8 ) times this stack does go out of range.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this is where your memory is leaking:

```
        Byte *newright=new Byte[4];
        newright=function_des(right,key48[i]);
        /*...*/
        delete[] newright;
```

You allocate memory, you assign it to a pointer, then you assign another value to pointer, so the delete[] frees newly referenced memory and the previously allocated memory is lost.

Also here:

```
Byte* des::function_des(Byte right[],Byte k[]){
    Byte *right_p=new Byte[6];
    Byte *B=new Byte[8];
    /*...*/
    B=permute(B,P,32,4);
    delete[] right_p;
}
```

How to fix it - don't overwrite your pointer variables like that, declare new pointer:

```
        Byte *newright=new Byte[4];
        Byte *really_newright=function_des(right,key48[i]);
        /* use really_newright instead of newright */
        delete[] newright;
        /* ... delete[] really_newright; delete it when appropriate ... */
```

And I'm not sure that you need dynamically allocate these temp arrays, but you dumped a lot of code so I'm not sure (maybe you call your methods recursively and if you allocate arrays on stack you will encounter stack overflow).

Comment: Thank you Mladen!
How exactly do I fix it. Do you propose I should not use new??

Comment: @SilentPro Never use `new`... except when you have to.

Comment: @SilentPro instead, give `std::vector<Byte>` a try.

Comment: Thanks Alex. Ill try that way and get back to you.

Comment: @Mladen
I guess I dont need dynamic allocation as pretty much everything in DES is hardcoded.
If I dont use new at all in the above cases how would it affect my code?

Comment: @SilentPro: Do not use dynamic memory allocation if you don't need it. Normal C arrays (i.e. `int my_array [6];`) or even C++ `std::array` work pretty much fine in most of the above code. Besides, allocating (and freeing) dynamic memory can be (most of the time is) much slower.

Comment: Thank you MLaden It solved my problem. Id keep the tips in mind Yaser and Alex.
Special thanks to Mladen for being able to read my practically impossible to read code in minutes!!